# How to Fix "An incompatible SQL Server version was detected" VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools, incompatibility

This Question is might be duplicated (But my issues isn't resolved yet).
I have Visual-Studio 2015 and I want to work on WPF application with VS Local DB /LINQ to SQl. But When I tried to create tables in local database following error appeared 
"An incompatible SQL Server version was detected."
This issue might be resolved by updating SSDT for VS-15. But here is the link for VS-17 not for VS-15 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017)

Furthermore I couldn't find any SSDT-Updates for VS-15 download link for Offline Installation..
Is there any solution for this problem ?
Thanks

Dear @MadBert here is Screenshot of Project Properties
[image]

Here is Setting Tab
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two options:

1: Change target platform in Project settings to be correct one.

[image: Project settings]

2: Check "Allow incompatible platform" in publish profile under advanced deployment options.

[image: publish Profile]

3: You were looking for older versions of SSDT. Please see [Previous releases of SQL Server Data Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/previous-releases-of-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-and-ssdt-bi?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thanks @MadBert for reply..
But I couldn't find Target Platform option in my VS.. and same for the 2nd..
I'm using VS-15

Comment: @BilalTahir For number 1, you need to right click on your project and go Properties.Then navigate to Project Settings tab. For number 2, you need to edit Publish Profile deployment settings.

Comment: Dear @MadBert in my case these options are not available, I have shared Screenshot in my Question statement by editing the Question..
Please have a look.. Thank You

Comment: @BilalTahir Can you try by going to Visual Studio Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> and look for SSDT update/installation please.